# No module named 'kebab' in django devserver

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I created an app called 'kebab' locally and it all works fine. I've added it to settings.py and url's and it's all good.
However, when we pull our local changes onto the development server, ubuntu returned the "no module named 'kebab'" error. We added it to settings.py on the devserver but still no luck. A little stumped at the moment. Any suggestions?
We're running Ubuntu and an Apache server.

Traceback:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named kebab
```

Comment: I assume you mean in our urls.py file.

Comment: Thing is, it worked fine locally, let me know what code you need

Comment: The error traceback might help... Im guessing you haven't set the python path or environment but guesses in the dark aren't very helpful

Comment: There we go. Hopefully it helps